# Why is this alertView nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

So, the code below generates an exception because the alertView is nil when I'm trying to show it.

Is there some reason this is a bad alloc/init combo?  Can this not be done in a class method or something?

Thanks.

```
+(void) Test
{
   UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"t"
                              message:@"message"
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@""
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];

   [alertView show];

}
```

Comment: try to declare it in strong or retain.

Comment: I tried in iOS 8 and it is working.

Comment: What is the exception? The code you posted should work fine with no error.

Comment: @rmaddy the code crashes (at least on simulator w/iOS7) due to an attempt by UIAlertView to insert nil into an array.

Comment: Can you update the question with the complete and exact error message. And what happens if you change `cancelButtonTitle:@""` to `cancelButtonTitle:nil`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with memory management, the only thing I am seeing here is that maybe iOS 7 doesn't like empty cancel buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to iOS 8, you must have a non-empty string for `cancelButtonTitle`. Change:

```
cancelButtonTitle:@""
```

To:

```
cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"
```

Comment: In iOS 8, even if setting cancelButtonTitle to nil, alert view is displayed. Of course setting nil is not correct and proper.